# RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation fails to pass a sanity check pygame and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, pycharm

I'm getting this error when trying to run programs on PyCharm which use numpy or pygame. I have both packages installed so I'm wondering what the error could be. In the console it says:

> RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:

Answer (score 2):

Which version of numpy do you have? `numpy1.19.4` has some issues with `Python 3.9` what you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503987/i-am-having-a-problem-with-using-pygame-and-numpy). Version `1.19.5` solved the issue. You can try to update `numpy` to the newest version: how to do it depends on how do you manage your packages. The simplest way is to use pip:

```py
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

I don't see any reports with `PyGame` regarding that bug. It might be solved after you update `numpy`. If not, you can try to update `PyGame`. If that fails, you can try to downgrade to `Python 3.8`.